# retain and release a delegate when using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

Since ASIHTTPRequests don't retain delegates, you might run into a situation where delegate gets deallocated before request is complete.

You can handle this situation by:

```
[request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
[request release];
```

But sometimes you want request to finish, and you don't want to cancel it. Is this the best way to acheive that

```
//Retain delegate    

[request delegate:[self retain]];

-(void): requestFinished: (ASIHTTPRequest *) request{
   [self release];
   ...
}

-(void): requestFailed: (ASIHTTPRequest *) request{
   [self release];
   ...
}
```

Comment: If you need this, you should probably consider redesigning your code logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a singleton class to handle all these requests.

I always use the following architecture for grouping the requests.

(1) If the requests are used to display the contents of a view controller, they'll be suspended when the view controller disappears, resumed when the view controller appears and  cancelled when the view controller is released.

(2) If the requests are used to send information to the server, and need to be there even when the view controller is released (e.g uploading photos), a singleton class will be used to managed all these requests.
    And we can also set up a screen to view all the back-end ongoing requests managed by this singleton.